# HBase: Records returned where field is not present

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

I have a person table in HBase like below -

```
ROW_KEY     COLUMN+CELL
dinesh      column='details:code',value=dr-01
dinesh      column='status:is_error',value=false
dinesh      column='time:date_created',value=1553747864740
dinesh      column='time:last_updated',value=1553747864740
alex        column='details:code',value=al-01
alex        column='time:date_created',value=1553747786521
alex        column='time:last_updated',value=1553747786521
```

I want to fetch only the records where is_error field is false. This attribute will be present only in certain rows. I tried to fetch it using SingleColumnValueFilter but its giving me all the records.

**Query:**

```
scan 'person', {FILTER=>"SingleColumnValueFilter('status','is_error',=,'binary:false')"}
```

**Output:**

```
ROW_KEY     COLUMN+CELL
dinesh      column='details:code',value=dr-01
dinesh      column='status:is_error',value=false
dinesh      column='time:date_created',value=1553747864740
dinesh      column='time:last_updated',value=1553747864740
alex        column='details:code',value=al-01
alex        column='time:date_created',value=1553747786521
alex        column='time:last_updated',value=1553747786521
```

The expected output should be only one row matching the given condition but it returns two rows where is_error field is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [a different constructor](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SingleColumnValueFilter.html#SingleColumnValueFilter-byte:A-byte:A-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CompareOperator-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ByteArrayComparable-boolean-boolean-) for your filter:

```
protected SingleColumnValueFilter(byte[] family,
                                  byte[] qualifier,
                                  CompareOperator op,
                                  ByteArrayComparable comparator,
                                  boolean filterIfMissing,
                                  boolean latestVersionOnly)
```

`filterIfMissing` will ensure that rows not containing your column aren't returned. I have no idea why this isn't default behaviour.

Your scan should be:

```
scan 'person', {FILTER=>"SingleColumnValueFilter('status','is_error', =, 'binary:false', true, true)"}
```